# Is possibile to download to Exchange 2013 mailbox an external Pop3 mailbox?

Tags: exchange-2013, pop3, connector

Once a time Exchange let download an external mailbox to a local mailbox through a "Microsoft Connector for POP3 Mailboxes". Then I could read my external/pop mail to a local exchange mailbox.
Is it possibile with 2013? I cannot find the connector anymore.

Comment: It doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Exchange server still running on SBS server?

For the feature(Download e-mail from a single POP3 mailbox to a single Exchange mailbox (user mailbox)), POP3 Connector on SBS could help realize it(**[Understanding the Microsoft Connector for POP3 Mailboxes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-essentials-sbs/cc747541(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**)

If your Exchange Server was not deployed on SBS server, as **Ed Crowley** said in the following thread: **[POP3 Connection Manager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/daa27dd0-212c-4993-b439-f1542996d4c9/pop3-connection-manager?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy)**, "**The POP3 connector is part of SBS, not Exchange.**", the feature is not available any more.

However, there are several tools could help build the connection between POP and Exchange mailboxes, the related link is for your reference: **[Connecting Exchange Server to a POP3 Account](https://www.slipstick.com/exchange/connecting-exchange-server-to-a-pop3-account/)**

Comment: I have Exchange 2013, not SBS.